# Error "TypeError: failed to fetch" is happening using alert(), but not using console.log()

Tags: reactjs, fetch, typeerror, use-effect, react-hook-form

"TypeError: failed to fetch" on page refresh.

Im getting the fetch error "TypeError: failed to fetch" when I refresh the page, but the issue just happens if i pass a state as fetch parameter, otherwise the application run fine.

That's the code:

```
const \[posts, setPosts\] = useState(\[\])

//Get posts
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://codeleap-test-api.herokuapp.com/posts", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
        }
    })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => setPosts(data))
        .catch(err => alert(err))
}, [])

// create new post
function createPost(post) {
    fetch("https://codeleap-test-api.herokuapp.com/posts", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(post)
    })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => console.log('Posts created'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}`
```

Now, if I pass the state "posts" inside the first useEffect brackets, I always get the error mentioned above. Like that:

`//get posts useEffect(() => {fetch...}, [posts])`

What can I do to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!